# Can anybody explain the concept of pluggable adapter to me with good example?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, adapter

Can anybody explain the concept of pluggable adapter to me with good example?

Answer (score 15):

From what I understood from a quick reading of Google results, a pluggable adapter is an adapter that isn't hard-coded against a specific adaptee. On the surface (the adapter's own interface), it's all the same but it can adapt to different adaptees with different interfaces. I found [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/98662/OO-Patterns-UML-Refactoring/What-is-pluggable-adapter) pretty explanatory:

> Basically, it allows you to put in an
>   adapter when the adaptee (receiver)
>   protocol is not known at compile time
>   by using reflection. When you create
>   the adapter instance, you pass it the
>   name of the adaptee's method to call,
>   and also any metadata that's necessary
>   to translate input types. When the
>   adapter receives a method call of the
>   target interface, it uses reflection
>   to call the corresponding method
>   specified on the adaptee.

And [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Viewer_-_Implementation_of_Pluggable_Adapter_Pattern):

> The main responsibility of the Viewer
>   is to populate a widget from a domain
>   model without making any assumptions
>   about domain itself. JFace viewer uses
>   the Delegating Objects mechanism in
>   Pluggable Adapter Pattern to implement
>   the above requirement.

[image: Facehugger in action]

Think of it as a facehugger from [Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(film)); when it hugs a face, all you see is the slimy back of the facehugger. You can poke it with a stick and try to pry off its arms (the adapter interface). But it basically can hug the face of any human (the adaptee), regardless of the face features. Maybe I'm pushing it a bit, but, hey, I love Alien.

Answer (score 3):

You can read [this article](http://www.guydavis.ca/seng/seng609.04/adapter.shtml) about adapter/pluggable pattern:

Table of content in this article:

```
* 1 Design Patterns
* 2 Intent of Adapter
* 3 Motivation
* 4 Structure
* 5 Applicability
* 6 Consequences
* 7 Implementation
      o 7.1 Known Uses and Sample Code
      o 7.2 Related Patterns
* 8 Conclusions
* 9 Appendix
      o 9.1 References
      o 9.2 Glossary
```

Quote:

> Smalltalk introduced the concept of a
>   "pluggable adapter" to describe
>   classes with built-in interface
>   adaptation. This interesting concept
>   allows for classes to be introduced
>   into existing systems that might
>   expect different interfaces to the
>   class. This technique can help promote
>   class reuse across modules and even
>   projects.

Here is a small example:

We have two classes - Foo & Boo that outputs some string to console. Adapter class can adapt methods from both classes to provide interface (SaySomething) required by client. Note that there is no dependency on interface name - we can easily adapt both SayHey and Bark methods.

```
class Foo 
{
    public static void SayHey() { Console.WriteLine("Hey!"); }
}

class Boo 
{
    public static void Bark() { Console.WriteLine("Woof!"); }
}

class Adapter 
{
    public Action SaySomething { get; private set;} // "pluggable" adapter

    public Adapter(Action saySomethingAction) 
    {
        SaySomething = saySomethingAction;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new Adapter(Foo.SayHey)).SaySomething();
        (new Adapter(Boo.Bark)).SaySomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did refer that article. I guess you also search that with Google. But it does not explain about Pluggable adapter clearly. It is referring to GoF book which I have read.

Comment: The link to the article is now broken.

Comment: So what a pluggable adapter do is that it let the interface called inside the class be passed when initializing adapter(i.e. your `new Adapter(Foo.SayHey)` and `(Boo.Bark)`)? I'm thinking about why this is useful...

Answer (score 0):

A distinguish Feature of the Pluggable Adapter is that the method called by the client and the method existing in the interface can be different.

```
 interface Ilegacy
    {
        float calculate(int a, int b);
    }
    class Legacy : Ilegacy
    {
        public float calculate(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
    class Adapter
    {
        public Func<int, int, float> legacyCalculator;
        public Adapter()
        {
            this.legacyCalculator = new Legacy().calculate;
        }
    }
    class Client
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            float result = new Adapter().legacyCalculator(5, 6);
        }
    }
```

This can normally acheived with the use of delegate,Func or Action in C#

Comment: Could you elaborate more about how this can be useful?