# What is pluggable adapter design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I am c++ developer and try to understand the design pattern .In structural pattern there is a specific pattern called adapter pattern.some how i understand this pattern from the GOF book.In this pattern ,there is pluggable adapter pattern,which very confusing and not able to understand it .Googled lot but not able to find a satisfactory answer.Can any one explain what is pluggable adapter design pattern ,with a c++ example ? and also the difference between normal adapter pattern and pluggable adapter pattern.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The below example fulfill this condition:

> adapter should support the adaptees(which are unrelated and have
> different interfaces)  using the same old target interface known to the
> client.

This example uses C++11 lambda to implement the same functionality like delegates.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <functional>

  //Adaptee 1
  struct CoffeMaker {
    void Brew (double quantity, double temp) const{
     std::cout << "I am brewing " << quantity <<"ml coffee @" << temp <<" degree C" <<std::endl; 
   }
  };

  //Adaptee 2 (having difference interface from Adaptee 2)
  struct  JuiceMaker{
    void Squeeze (double quantity) const{
      std::cout << "I am making " << quantity <<"ml Juice" <<std::endl; 
   }
  };

  // Target
  struct Beverage{
    virtual void getBeverage (int quantity) = 0;
  };

  // Adapter
  class Adapter : public Beverage{
    std::function<void(int)> Request;

  public:
    Adapter(CoffeMaker *cm1){
      Request = [cm1](int quantity){
        cm1->Brew(quantity,80);
      };
      delete cm1;
    }

    Adapter(JuiceMaker *jm1){
      Request = [jm1](int quantity){
        jm1->Squeeze(quantity);
      };
      delete jm1;
    }

    void getBeverage(int quantity){
      Request(quantity);
    }
  };

  //Client
  int main(){
    Adapter adp1(new CoffeMaker());
    adp1.getBeverage(30);
    
    Adapter adp2(new JuiceMaker());
    adp2.getBeverage(40);

  }
```

Though this example is based on the this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527730-01-04.aspx) but I have some objections in their pluggable adapter example

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the answers to this question are satisfactory for you. I think the pluggable cannot be explained better: [Can anybody explain the concept of pluggable adapter to me with good example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449424/can-anybody-explain-the-concept-of-pluggable-adapter-to-me-with-good-example)